# after session time out getting error - object reference not set to an instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm making `Li` menu visible to some users only, but after session time out its getting error:

> Object reference not set to an instance.

How to avoid this error if session time out.

```
if (Session["LoggedInUser"].ToString() == "admin" || Session["LoggedInUserLower"].ToString() == "admin")
{
     liBatch.Visible = true;
}
else
{
     liBatch.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if session object is not null before calling `ToString` on it

```
if((Session["LoggedInUser"] != null && Session["LoggedInUser"].ToString()== "admin") || 
    (Session["LoggedInUserLower"] != null && Session["LoggedInUserLower"].ToString() == "admin"))
   {
        liBatch.Visible = true;
   }
   else
   {
       liBatch.Visible = false;
   }
```